# Merge n lists alternating k elements from each

Tags: python

I was trying to merge an arbitrary number of lists (contained inside a list) into a single one taking a certain number of k elements from each. Each list can have different size.

```
k = 2
mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[…]
print(modified_mylist)
> output: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

I was searching for a 'pythonic' solution.

Edit: here's a more detailed process of what I'm trying to achieve

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

I split each sublist into 'chunks' of k (2 in this case) elements

```
[ [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ], [ [5, 6], [7] ], [ [8, 9], [10, 11] ], [ [12, 13], [14, 15] ] ]
```

And then I merge alternatively each chunks into a single list

```
[ [1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 9], [12, 13], [3, 4], [7], [10, 11], [14, 15] ]
```

Flattening the list it becomes

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

Comment: 'taking a certain number of k elements from each.' is not sufficiently precise.
What did you try?

Comment: What happens when a list "runs out" compared to other lists?

Comment: @PeterWood it iterates through, getting the first two (or whatever is left) out of the lists and appends it to the magic list.

Comment: @hpchavaz I tried to explain it more visually which I think it's better than to use interacted phrases

Comment: @PeterWood it should just stop taking values from that list since has been 'exhausted'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `more_itertools.chunked`
2. `zip`
3. then flatten: `itertools.chain` and `sum` trick

```
import itertools as it
import more_itertools as mit

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

def magic(data, k):
    l = [list(mit.chunked(sub, k)) for sub in data]
    l = list(zip(*l))
    return(sum(it.chain(*l),[]))

magic(data,2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

Notes:

- We can avoid intermediary lists with generators:

  ```
  def magic(data, k):
      g = (mit.chunked(sub, k) for sub in data)
      g = zip(*g)
      return(sum(it.chain(*g),[]))
  ```
- or a oneliner, at the expense of readability:

  ```
  magic = lambda d, k: sum(it.chain(*zip(*(mit.chunked(s,k) for s in d))), [])
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single list comprehension:

```
k = 2
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

out = [e for i in range(0,max(map(len,L)),k) for sl in L for e in sl[i:i+k]]

print(out)
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with some for loops. Perhaps not the most pythonic.

```
k = 3
mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

def magic(mylist, k):
    # Empty list to store the chunked elements in
    magic_list = []
    # Loop over the list based on the length of the longest sublist and value of k
    for i in range(0,max(map(lambda x: len(x), mylist)), k):
        # Loop over the sublists
        for l in mylist:
            # Select the values in the span defined by K
            magic_list += l[i:i+k]

    return magic_list

magic(mylist, k)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 4, 11, 15]
```

Comment: That actually works well :) I'll wait for some more pythonic answers but so far that seems to be the correct solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

I started writing a long response, but that's clearly not what you are looking for.

What we can do here is reverse each of the lists (to save time complexity for later) and continue to pop off values until there is nothing left.

```
def magic(l, k):
    result = []
    # Reverse list
    l = [list(reversed(a)) for a in l]
    done = [False for v in l] # Keep track of which ones are done
    while False in done:
        # Iterate through,
        # removing the first two (last because of the reverse) where possible
        for i in range(len(l)):
            # Add to results k times
            for j in range(k):
                if len(l[i]) > 0:
                    result.append(l[i].pop()) # Add result
            # Check if that sub-array is empty
            if len(l[i]) == 0:
                done[i] = True
    return result
```

While it may not be a one-liner and fancy, it is much easier to understand and definitely works with your example. EDIT: it now works with any k