# merge lists alternating k items from each

Tags: kdb

given list of lists, how to merge them into a single list taking up to `k` items at a time from each of the lists until all items are merged?

for example, the following input and output is expected:

```
q)alternate[1] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
"adfbegchi"
```

for `k~1` items at a time, the solution is:

```
q)mesh:{raze[y]rank x}          / https://code.kx.com/phrases/sort/#mesh
q)alternate:{mesh[raze where each 1&{0|x-1}\[count each x];x]}
q)alternate ("abc";"de";"fghi")
"adfbegchi"
```

the above works because:

```
q)mesh[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 2;] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
"adfbegchi"
```

How to elegantly generalize `alternate` for any `k<=max count each x` ? python solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049142/merge-n-lists-alternating-k-elements-from-each)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the below should achieve this

```
q)f:{raze[y]iasc raze(x-1)|til'[count'[y]]};
q)f[1;("abc";"de";"fghi")]
"adfbegchi"
q)f[2;("abc";"de";"fghi")]
"abdefgchi"
```

Comment: awesome, this is the fastest solution so far (added the benchmark of the three), so marked this answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the fastest solution, substituting `x` for the hardcoded `1` in the `alternate` function above, and thus making it dyadic:

```
q)alternate:{mesh[raze where each x&{0|y-x}[x]\[count each y];y]}
q)alternate[2] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
"abdefgchi"
q)alternate[2] (1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)
1 2 5 6 8 9 12 13 3 4 7 10 11 14 15
q)alternate[3] (1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 4 11 15
```

edit:
naïve benchmark comparison with @terrylynch 's `alt` and @Matthew Madill's `f` :

```
q)\t:10000 f[2] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
49
q)\t:10000 alternate[2] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
56
q)\t:10000 alt[2] ("abc";"de";"fghi")
87
q)\t:10000 f[3] (1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)
55
q)\t:10000 alternate[3] (1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)
61
q)\t:10000 alt[3] (1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)
103
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any faster or cleaner but a different approach:

```
q)alt:{(raze/)value each(s;::;)each til max count each s:x cut'y};

q)alt[1;("abc";"de";"fghi")]
"adfbegchi"
q)alt[2;("abc";"de";"fghi")]
"abdefgchi"

q)alt[2;(1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)]
1 2 5 6 8 9 12 13 3 4 7 10 11 14 15
q)alt[3;(1 2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10 11;12 13 14 15)]
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 4 11 15
```

I was hoping to use [case](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#case) but unfortunately case doesn't like lists of different count (that aren't atomic values)

Comment: lateral thinking, many thanks! seems like `cut` - instead of manipulating indices - and multiple adverbs both add some overhead. added simple benchmarks in my answer

Comment: Yeah. The `mesh` is nice, I don't remember seeing that on code.kx

Comment: `mesh` appears to be using `iasc` twice (as in `rank`), so @Matthew's solution seems more direct than `mesh`